# How to count rows based on another column?

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I am a beginner at SQL and I am using Microsoft Access. I am trying to create count tables based on Object Def. However, some objects in Object Def have a related column that indicates how many objects are within that row. Most objects in Object Def are singular objects and are represented with a blank field.

[image: Example table]

I want the output to look something like this:

```
Object Def  Total

Cat         3

Dog         4

Rat         4
```

Comment: It should be 4. It's a combination of the object count and the row. If the object count is left blank, it really means there's 1 object. In the data set, rows that have one object are blank in the object count column.

Comment: make sure when you post Questions, that you only include the fields in which the data will come from....there are way too many literal Answerers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
SELECT object_def,
    SUM(Nz(object_count, 1)) AS total
FROM table_name
GROUP BY object_def;
```

Comment: @pham-x-bach...i stand corrected...and deleted post

Answer (score 0):

For ease of testing for your scenario: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1e9d5/3

Otherwise, `Group By` gets you the objective you are trying to obtain.